# Comparison between two groups of time series?

Tags: regression, logistic, repeated-measures, sas

I have two groups of people. One group of people are healthy and the other group of people is sick. For people in both groups, I let them do exercise for 10 mins and then let them rest for 3 mins. I measure their blood pressure over these 13 mins. I am wondering whether I can use the blood pressure over these 13 mins to tell whether a person is sick or not?

In other words, whether the blood pressure varies between the two groups of people. Can we use the blood pressures, 13 times, as the biomarker to differentiate the health and sickness.

My intuition is to use logistic model to establish the outcome healthiness with the predictor blood pressure. But the problem is the outcome is not the repeated measure, while the predictor is.

The SAS GEE procedure handles the outcome repeated, not the opposite direction. How should I tackle this problem?

Comment: How many people in each group?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a repeated measures experiment, since the outcome is not repeated, it is only measured once for each participant.

There are various possibilities for analysis:

- You could build a (logistic) regression model, and build features from the blood pressure measurements. I'm not sure about the best way to do that ...
- manova (multivariate anova)

See [T-tests, manova or logistic regression - how to compare two groups?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/t-tests-manova-or-logistic-regression-how-to-compare-two-groups)  for a comparison!