# Non-parametric statistical test to compare a continuous and dichotomous variable in the same group

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, correlation, biostatistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I want to compare between the level of Th17 cells in the blood of a group patients with Sarcoidosis, and whether or not it is correlated with them having fibrosis.
So, a continuous variable and a dichotomous variable, and one group, not two. Mann Whitney can't be applied as far I understand. So, what test to use if the data are not normal? Also, what test to use of one of the variables is not dichotomous, but can have multiple values??

Comment: So you are comparing the distribution of some continuous variable between two groups? Can you tell us some more, like sample size, and show us some plots? But maybe try Wilcoxon test

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sample size is 25, no, not 2 groups, just one group of patients. I want to check if there is a correlation between the level of Th17 in their blood (continuous variable), and whether or not they have fibrosis (dichotomous variable).

Comment: Fibrosis or not seem to define two groups (maybe in your case subgroups) for the purpose of the wilcox test. If you had more observations, maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190156/t-tests-manova-or-logistic-regression-how-to-compare-two-groups

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I was thinking of an alternative to the point bieserial when data are not normal?

Comment: What question do you have for your data to (hopefully) answer, if the Th17 level is high/lower in the fibrosis group than in the  control or healthy group?

Comment: @Dave I want to answer wheher the increase of Th17 in some patients correlates with fibrosis. No healthy group. Just one group of patients, some have fibrosis, and some don't. I have their data of Th17 cells levels. I want to check if it correlates with fibrosis.

Comment: That sounds like a two-group comparison, exactly what a t-test or Wilcoxon test addresses. What do you see differently? (Do you, for instance, have “before-and-after” measurements for each group?)

Comment: @Dave 
unequal group sizes (12 data points in the "No Fibrosis" group and 13 in the "Fibrosis" group). The Wilcoxon signed-rank test is applicable only when the compared groups have the same number of samples? or I am mistaken?

Comment: Often, and here in particular, “Wilcoxon test” refers to the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test, which does not require equal group sizes. The signed-rank test bearing Wilcoxon’s name is analogous to the paired t-test and, thus, requires equal group sizes but is a different test. Both the paired t-test and signed-rank test also require a natural pairing of the points, such as before-and-after. $//$ One of your hang-ups seems to be a lack of normality. If you had normality, would a two-sample t-test make sense?

Comment: @Dave
Thanks, yes, then in this case the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U test could be applied?

Comment: This sounds like a situation where WMWU can be used. WMWU is basically asking if the two groups have different distributions.